# two finger scrolling and tap to click stopped working in Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish

Tags: upgrade, scrolling

I've just updated and first thing I check has stopped working. It's an HP EliteBook 820 G2 and I updated from Impish 21.10. Can anyone suggest fixes or troubleshooting?

I tried editing the settings to toggle scrolling and tap to click on and off. I rebooted afterwards. No joy.

Edit 20220515 (morning): I just turned my laptop on again for the first time since originally posting this and both functions are working. No idea why. I haven't changed anything. Maybe it just needed a rest after the update. (:

Edit 20220515 (evening): The problem is back again! Totally unpredictable and won't be remedied by reboots. I run Unity and switching between that and GNOME does nothing. Very, very annoying. If I log in to GNOME Classic then two finger scrolling suddenly works but tap to click doesn't. I can turn scrolling off in settings and it stops working. It only starts again if, after I turn it back, I also toggle tap to click! This is cray.

Comment: This might help you to understand the problem better
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=262139
https://vitux.com/how-to-activate-two-finger-scrolling-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution to this was to do a clean install of Ubuntu22. Now everything works. I guess there were so many UIs installed that one of them was conflicting with Jammy for control of the input. This was probably the smart solution anyway as I think I'd updated all the way from Bionic Beaver, or even Xenial.

Anyway, trouble-free Ubuntuing is restored once more. :)

Comment: why is this an accepted answer? Reinstalling Ubuntu should not be the default to go when troubleshooting

Comment: It's the accepted answer because it solved the problem. Read what I tried and the contex. A fresh install was necessary.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS is definitely **not** the right thing to do. This problem can be fixed by simply uninstalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:

`apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Answer (score 3):

It works for me (gnome 42.2):

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse
```

Comment: My tap to click and double-tap-to-drag randomly stop working in 22.04 with a synaptics touchpad and this does fix it, but it doesn't explain what goes wrong. This happened for me when I made the switch from kernel 5.19 to 6.2.xx.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Mouse and Touchpad` and on Device select `SynPS/2 Synaptic TouchPad` or something similar. There you should have a tab `Touchpad` where you can select `Scrolling mode` and `Tap touchpad to click`.

In this image you can see the options (I have Tap touchpad to click deactivated, but you can activate it yourself of course)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried those settings many different ways and they don't change anything.

Comment: Please edit your question in order to add things you have tried so others are aware of that just by reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue started after adding touchegg then reinstall using following
$ sudo apt remove touchegg
$ sudo apt install touchegg

if the issue didn't happned due to adding touchegg even then you may try by add touchegg (it may help on your device, worth a try) by adding following PPA
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install touchegg